# how to change textview using firebase? help needed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, textview

i dont know anything about app developing sorry if this has been asked before but i looked all over and couldnt find any solution.

so here is my problem.

in main activity there are three buttons named A B C.
if u click A then A1 activity will open which also has three buttons A1,A2,A3
now if u click A1 you will get values such as 0,1,2,3. i have set this values by using textview and i named this activity as A1_values.
now i want to change those values on daily basis.i know i can do it by using firebase but i dont know how to do it.

do i have to code in main activity or only in A1_values java file.

main activity code///

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView ( R.layout.activity_main );
    }


    public void goToactivity_A1 (View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent (this,A1.class);
        startActivity ( intent );
    }
}
```

A1 activity code

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView ( R.layout.activity_a1 );
    }


    public void goToactivity_A1_values (View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent ( this, A1_values.class );
        startActivity ( intent );

    }
}
```

A1_values code

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView ( R.layout.activity_a1_values );
    }
}
```

if there is another method i will be happy to do it.  also what changes needs to be done in firebase to use realtime database i have already connected firebase to app but there is name and value and i dont know what to do with that.

Comment: So to be clear, there are 2 activities for A, (A1 and A1_values)? And you want to tranfer the value between them?

Comment: yes there are two activities for A and in A1_values there is textview which shows value 0,1,2,3  and i just want to change those value day after day.thats my problem.i have been searching for 5 days and still couldnt find answer. @Ticherhaz

Comment: how the value will change?

Comment: YEAH thats the question.@Ticherhaz

Comment: What I mean is, you will add the value manually or ? if the day comes, it will update itself?

Comment: i will add maunally but if i add manually then everyone has to update app to see those updated values again,right? so using firebase i should be able to do it but i dont know how to do it. @Ticherhaz

Comment: so, example situation is, you add/update/delete a value at the A1_values.java (activity) , and the other users (other phone) can see the value change? is that it?